MERN Cookies and Dockefile
I am deploying my application with MERN stack that uses a middleware to check if there is a cookie with token to authorize the user. In localhost the code works fine, while on Render it cannot read the cookie present.I also use containers with Docker for frontend, backend and mongoDB. I leave the link of my Github repository: https://github.com/Progetto2324NSD/Progetto.git
I tried changing the cookie settings but it still doesn't work, any solutions?
